# How to get the an order through rest api?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

Get the an order through rest api

Here is the script i tried

```
<?php

    $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "Abcd1234");
    $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($token);

    //$data = array("id"=>1);
    $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/000000021");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));


$token = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($token);

//var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

error message:

> {"message":"The consumer isn't authorized to access
>   %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Sales::sales"}

the admin already has "ALL" resources, i don't know why the error message will show that.

Comment: Have you checked your password?

Comment: because i have checked your code and it's returning perfect data

Comment: @RutveeSojitra are you using version 2.3?

Comment: yes Magento 2.3.1

Comment: thanks, i just checked to use another website, it works. but i don't know why it didn't work for the original one

Comment: Have you made other admin users?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PHP handler used by Apache on the Magento server. I changed from cgi to suphp and the requests started to work. Interestingly, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028498/problem-with-magento-2-rest-authentication/59530132, POST requests would always work, but GET requests would fail. I have no idea why changing the handler solves the problem. Good luck.